# Ajax request to Wcf Service get error Object object

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have a method WCF, which returns a JSON:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QlOis.png)

the client has a script that should take the data from the wcf service
Script:

```js
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>



<script>

    function createCORSRequest(method, url) {
        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        if ("withCredentials" in xhr) {
            xhr.open(method, url, true);
        } else if (typeof XDomainRequest != "undefined") {
            xhr = new XDomainRequest();
            xhr.open(method, url);
        } else {
            xhr = null;
        }
        return xhr;
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {
        $('#btn').click(function () {
            $.ajax({
                url: 'http://192.168.200.100/Searching.BE.Service//WCFRESTService.svc/GetCategories',
                method: 'get',
                contentType: 'application/json;charset=utf-8',
                dataType: 'json',
                success:function(data)
                {
                    alet(data.Announcing[0].Categories.id);
                },
                error: function (error)
                {
                    alert(error);
                }
            })
            var request = createCORSRequest("get", "http://192.168.200.100/Searching.BE.Service//WCFRESTService.svc/GetCategories");
            request.send();
        })
    })
    
</script>
<input id="btn" type="button" />
```

After click button i have this error: Object object

and i have console message:

SCRIPT7002: XMLHttpRequest: Network error 0x80070005, Access Denied .

SEC7120: Source http: // localhost: 4945 is not found in the header Access-Control-Allow-Origin ..

How to solve these problems?

Comment: Are you able to browser this through browser `http://192.168.200.100/Searching.BE.Service//WCFRESTService.svc`

Comment: @MairajAhmad, This is because the browser http://i.stack.imgur.com/QlOis.png

Answer (score 0):

Well, because your web server is running locally (see the 192.168...) address, I can't test it, but your error messages tell me the following:

The first one indicates that you are trying to access an unavailable resource. Try visiting the url with your browser, and see if that gives a response. Also in, http://192.168.200.100/Searching.BE.Service//WCFRESTService.svc/GetCategories, the double slash might indicate it's the wrong url.

The second error is not complete, but are you maybe serving the web page from a different server than the api? Because a quick google search reveals that it has something to do with a cross-site request.

Comment: my browser returned:http://i.stack.imgur.com/QlOis.png. I tried to remove the double slash, but nothing has changed.

Comment: Are you serving the web page from a different server than the api?

Comment: I do not have another server than api